# Driving a stepper motor via USB and OSX

Tags: usb, stepper-motor

I am a total newbie for electronics and hardware programming, but I would really like to start practicing it. As a first achievement, I would like to find a simple step motor and drive it through a simple USB connection. The easiest (less HW/less SW) is the way to achieve this, the better.

What kind of hardware and software do I need ? How can I achieve this first step? Please consider as you are explaining it to a child. I really know nothing about this activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd buy an Arduino and the Adafruit stepper shield.

http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=81

They have some great documentation:

http://www.ladyada.net/make/mshield/

Comment: is it required to pass through arduino to do this ?

Comment: Yes, the shield provides the electronics to drive the motors. The control logic and USB interface is on the Arduino.